# Moving a Camera in SpriteKit advanced

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to make a camera like in the video bellow

// Please watch the video first :)
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nryuCql2k9A

I try this

```
// moveWorld is true when the game lunch

    if(moveWorld){
        moveWorld = false
        rightHeroBorder = hero.position.x + (hero.frame.size.width * 2)
        leftHeroBorder = hero.position.x - (hero.frame.size.width * 2)
    }

    // move world to the right
    if(hero.position.x > rightHeroBorder){
        let diff = hero.position.x - rightHeroBorder
        rightHeroBorder = hero.position.x + 1
        leftHeroBorder = hero.position.x - 1
        self.world.position.x -= diff
    }

    // move world to the left
    if(hero.position.x < leftHeroBorder){
        let diff = leftHeroBorder - hero.position.x
        leftHeroBorder = hero.position.x - 1
        rightHeroBorder = hero.position.x + 1
        self.world.position.x += diff
    }
```

The result is not what I want

- in the beginning the world don't move
- but when the node passes rightHeroBorder or leftHeroBorder it starts to move
- If the node move a little, the world will move (doesnt detects the borders)
- if the node continue to move to the right, less of the right part of screen is visible (this should be opposite)

This is hard, but I don't want to center the node and the world.
Hopefully people with more experience will help

I'am asking about x coordinate system, but you can help with the y as well